# Getting error "Variable used within its own initial value"

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database, error-handling

I am writing a new bit of code that allows a user to upload an image to a post that will be saved in Firebase database and storage. Then it will be shown in a UITableView on a separate Viewcontroller. On the part of code where I want to save the photo url to my database I am getting an error "Variable used within its own initial value". I have looked at other threads covering this issue and when I follow their advice I get a new set of errors. Here is what my code looks like and where I am getting the error. If there are any suggestions that would be great, thank you!
Here is code:

```
func postWithImageAndText() {

    var imagesArray = [AnyObject]()

    let postLength = textView.text.count
    let numImages = imagesArray.count
    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let pictureStorageRef = storageRef.child("users/profile/\(uid)/media")

    let lowResImageData = (imagesArray[0] as! UIImage).jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.50)

            if(postLength>0 && numImages>0)
            {
                let uploadTask = pictureStorageRef.putData(lowResImageData!,metadata: nil)

                {metadata,error in

                    if (error == nil) {
                    let downloadUrl = storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in

                        guard let userProfile = UserService.currentUserProfile else { return }

                        let childUpdates = [
                            "author": [
                                "uid": userProfile.uid,
                                "username": userProfile.fullname,
                                "photoURL": userProfile.photoURL.absoluteString
                            ],
                            "text": self.textView.text!,
                            "picture": downloadUrl!.absoluteString,
                            "timestamp": ["sv.":"timestamp"]
                        ] as [String:Any]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

`

Error is happening on this part: `"picture": downloadUrl!.absoluteString,`

Comment: Post code as text, not as an image. You can write a comment for instance to point out any errors etc. Please update the question.

Comment: Which line do you get the error ? is it let downloadUrl …. Could you post the code, not an image, so that one can test how curly braces are balanced. Can the return type of the closure { metadata, error in … be inferred or do you need to explicit { (metadata, error) -> SomeType in …

Comment: @JoakimDanielson code has been posted as requested.

Comment: In the closure where you get the error you have a parameter `url`, maybe that is what you should use instead of `downloadUrl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see yo got an "Variable used within its own initial value" error, that means you try to access initial value of variable within this variable, its not a good behavior. 
I also see you dont use any data from your completion block, so try to use `nil` instead of your completion block and then try to access your `downloadURL` variable

Answer (score 1):

Your updated code:

```
func postWithImageAndText() {

    var imagesArray = [AnyObject]()

    let postLength = textView.text.count
    let numImages = imagesArray.count
    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let pictureStorageRef = storageRef.child("users/profile/\(uid)/media")

    if let lowResImageData = (imagesArray[0] as! UIImage).jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.50) {

      if(postLength>0 && numImages>0)
            {
               pictureStorageRef.putData(lowResImageData, metadata: metaData) { (metadata, error) in

                if error != nil {

                    print("Failed to upload image:", error as Any)

                }

                pictureStorageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

                    if error != nil {

                        print(error!)
                    }
                    if let imageUrl = url?.absoluteString {

                        guard let userProfile = UserService.currentUserProfile else { return }

                        let childUpdates = [
                            "author": [
                                "uid": userProfile.uid,
                                "username": userProfile.fullname,
                                "photoURL": userProfile.photoURL.absoluteString
                            ],
                            "text": self.textView.text!,
                            "picture": imageUrl,
                            "timestamp": ["sv.":"timestamp"]
                        ] as [String:Any]

                    }

                })

         }
      }
   }
}
```